# How to send Audio/Video over internet to multiple clients?

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, vpn, openvpn

I have designed a virtual classroom software for students with disabilities, it is being used by some local colleges. The limitation of the software is that the students within a Local Area Network (LAN) are able to connect with server in order to receive audio/video data. I have used sockets to connect clients with server. Now the demand for the software has increased and students outside of the LAN want to connect to server using their internet connection. I am aware that I have to rewrite the server/client connectivity modules, but I am not sure how to go about connecting clients to server using internet.
I think one way is to use a vpn but I am not really sure.
Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why roll your own solution here if you're confused about how placing servers on the internet works? Wouldn't YouTube do? If you need to stream live video, that's also available, or you could use ustream for that, etc.

Comment: (You could certainly enable VPN access to your LAN, and that would make it unnecessary to change anything in your existing code - the server should appear as a local network computer to the clients, using the same IP adress as well.)

Comment: @millimoose It uses kinect sensors to make using the software easy for deaf, blind and paralyzed students. I wouldn't get that by using Youtube, also it uses live video/audio streaming.

Comment: So why is your software restricted to LAN access right now? Remove that restriction and you should be able to just make the server publically accessible. (Not necessarily a good idea for security reasons but still. It should make deployments easier in general if you don't rely on details of the networking setup.)

Comment: @millimoose I really don't have any experience with VPN that's why I was hoping for some guidance. I am reading quite a lot about VPN, specially about OpenVPN.

Comment: @millimoose Because right now I am using Sockets and the clients have server IP and port and connect to that, I don't know how to connect clients outside LAN.

Comment: I'd recommend L2TP/IPSEC instead. It's natively supported by Windows and OS X clients, and I believe Windows Server also has builtin server software for it.

Comment: You connect any computer to any computer on the internet using a server IP and port number. The server just has to have a publically available IP. This is a deployment / networking issue, not a programming one.

Comment: @millimoose Ok thanks I will read about L2TP/IPSEC, I think connecting clients to the server without some kind encryption/authentication would be very unreliable.

Comment: It has nothing to do with reliability. It is however a good idea if you want to mitigate security issues. Exposing a server you handcoded to the public internet is not a great idea, with a VPN the pool of potential attackers will be people with access to the VPN credentials. (And the VPN software will likely have more security.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)First, the good news: You may not have to rewrite your client server code (at least not *completely*)

2)This question may be better suited for serverfault

3)Get with your IT staff to discuss your needs. Developing the app without consulting them is asking for trouble, because they're going to be the ones to ensure the proper firewall ports are opened. Even if you *had* a VPN, without consulting them there's no guarantee it would even work. Because you would need

4)A routable IP address. Yes, DYNDNS or something similar would work, but that introduces another single point of failure. No IT staff? Then

5)Find an IT consultant knowledgeable in basic networking, or make heavy use of serverfault.

Comment: "Get someone who knows about IT/sysops" is probably the most responsible suggestion here.

Comment: @millimoose yes that's what I'm driving him towards, but some people are really *DIY*, so there's that lol.